# Jquery ui date picker being blocked by 'previous entries' from form

Tags: jquery, django-forms

I have a jQuery UI datepicker, it works great, but if you click in the form field the 'previous' entered entries pop up.  I think this is due to the fact it took me a while to implement the datepicker.  (but it will be same story if someone manually enters a date) can I suppress the previous entries somehow?  Screenshot given for example.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am correct you need to disable the browser's autocomplete system, adding the html attribute `autocomplete="off"` to the input you are attaching the datepicker. Or if you want to disable it into the entire form put it in the `<form>` tag, like so:

```
<input type="text" name="myinput" autocomplete="off" />
```

or

```
<form method="get" name="myform" autocomplete="off"></form>
```

Comment: Awesome heck didn't even know that existed.

Comment: Glad this helped! :)